# Can I avoid submission of a React form before the state of all controlled fields was set

Tags: reactjs, redux

*(I know that this is a simple question. Before posting I have tried to find the answer in previous questions. There are many questions regarding setState being asynchronous, about that you can use a callback function, etc., but I didn't find a question similar to the following).*

When implementing a simple form in React, like the one that is shown [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) (under the `controlled components` title, also copied below):

Since `setState` is asynchronous, the example isn't guaranteed to work, right? (Since `handleSubmit` prints `this.state.value`, but there is no guarantee that it has been set already, when `handleSubmit` is called).

Is there a way to ensure that `handleSubmit` is called only after the state changes of all controlled components in a form have been done (and without using redux or something similar)?

Here is the code, copied from the [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) (I am copying it to make sure it can be read even if the URL changes):

```
lass NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can make the submit button disabled...  `disabled = {this.state.value == ''}`

Comment: Or, if you want to get creative, you can add a boolean variable called `submittable` to your state.  Set it to false at the beggining of your handleChange function (or any other function that changes state) and set it back to true at the end of the function when your function's logic is completed.  Then have your handleSubmit function check to see if the submittable state is true before it dispatches the submit logic

Comment: Your concern only occurs when using `this.state` right after `setState`. In piratical, the state is updated when the user triggered `onClick` event. If you want to use `state` immediately, you can always `async handleChange` method and then `await setState`, but I don't think it is necessary here.

Comment: Thank you all!
EgorEgorov  - not sure it makes sense to disable the submit button when the user filled all values.
MEnf - there are multiple handle changes...
FisNan - any guarantee for all state updates before onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure you have a current value of an input inside `handleSubmit` use the passed SyntheticEvent to [access inputs from a form](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements).

```
lass NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const inputValue = form.elements["user_name"].value;
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + inputValue);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name="user_name" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the other parts of the example provided in my question, with the required modifications?

Comment: Hmmm... interesting, I wasn't aware of this functionality. Will it work always in react with its virtual dom? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I use it sometimes when I don't need state. It should work as it's [documented](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview) - _"Every SyntheticEvent object has the following attributes: ... DOMEventTarget currentTarget_

Comment: Yes, supported for DOM but react.js is using a virtual DOM... Thanks. It will be interesting to offer this as an edit to the react.js documentation where the example comes from and see what they say... :)

Comment: You don’t understand what Virtual DOM means(it is misleading name). It does not replace Browser API it simply means that it keeps internaly state of html document (in JavaScript objects).